# Is it possible to get instagram media for a location with a foursquare id in a single call?

Tags: api, foursquare, instagram

I have a bunch of foursquare ids and I want to be able to pull instagram media with those foursquare ids.

Currently I only see one way to do this and it requires two API calls. You must first do a call to the search API using foursquare_v2_id ([example call](https://api.instagram.com/v1/locations/search?access_token=%3CACCESS_TOKEN%3E&foursquare_v2_id=447bf8f1f964a520ec331fe3)). That will return the instagram ID. Then I must do a second call to the media API using the instagram id to retrieve media ([example call](https://api.instagram.com/v1/locations/3000299/media/recent?access_token=%3CACCESS_TOKEN%3E)).

Does anyone know how to achieve these results (getting media for a location based on just a foursquare_id) with only one api call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After contacting Instagram it is clear that there is no way to do this at this time. If that ever changes I will come back and re-answer this question with the proper solution.

Comment: You should be able to query the `/locations/search` with the foursquare id to get the instagram id, then query `/locations/location-id/media/recent`- it is two requests though.

Answer (score 2):

You can get this information through the foursquare API, with the venues/photos endpoint. See the documentation [here](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/photos).

This will return a list of photos for the venue, including their source. You can use this to either return all images for a venue, or just those from instagram.

Comment: Instagram has more than just foursquare photos though. I want to pull instagram photos based on foursquare venue id because I will get more than whats just on foursquare and all i have is foursquare venue id.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to user below api to get instagram images:

```
https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/423a1a00f964a5202f201fe3/photos?oauth_token=Z5RRDGQUWEAFCANX2OT0R2O5QUWYOP1EMOCNXT1PQWKMHVNG&v=20130706&limit=200
```

Using foursquare id and foursquare oaurh token you can get perticular venue images.

In response, you can check "source":{"name":"Instagram","url":"http://instagram.com"}.
source name is Instagram means it is a instagram image.

```
Refer: https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/photos
```